# Where will Python be logging errors for me (moving from PHP)

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling

I am a PHPer new to Python (2.7 on Win32) and I would like to know where Python is shoving any errors it finds?

Do I need to turn something on, if so where do I do that?

Or, is the idea that you develop using a shell and watch errors spat out via that?

Please share any other good Python debugging/sanity-saving mechanisms you wish you'd known about earlier - or if you have switched from PHP perhaps you can tell me what the Python equivalents of :

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 1);
display_errors();
trigger_error();
var_dump();
```

Try and Exceptions looks fairly similar.

I will probably stumble across these answers myself in time, but in the meantime this issue is bugging me (no pun intended).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not a web dev guy, but about errors in Python in general: Python doesn't have what PHP calls errors, it has exceptions. Python will *never* silence one of those, unless of course there's a `try` around the code that caused it with an `except` clause that matches the exception raised *and* the code under `except` doesn't re-raise it. Execution stops completely (of course not the whole web server, propably just the request handler) when an exception is left unhandled. When that happens, it also gives a traceback by default, although I'd expect most web frameworks to change that.

Comment: Thx, looks like I should stop worrying and wait until I adopt a Framework judging by delnan an Thomas Ks replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python development is normally done in a shell, and you get a full traceback printed out on any uncaught exception.

If you want to log errors to file, have a look at the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging). You can either catch exceptions directly, or override the `sys.excepthook` function which is called for an uncaught error. If you're using a framework for e.g. web development, it may have mechanisms to do this sort of thing already.